# My reputation was decreased and reputation tab shows only increases

Tags: support, reputation

Also, "Today" says "-15" while "Week" says "-5", how is that possible?

See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Don't the today and week values say *negative* 15 and 5, respectively?

Comment: unaccpets and unaccept/accepts wreak havoc see my post earlier this week

Comment: What waffles said. Someone unaccepted one of your answers. No, you can't know which one. No, it won't be implemented as a feature any time soon. Yes, this is very annoying. :)

Comment: Here's the link for your convenience: [Why is my reputation total for today off by 15 points?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104522/why-is-my-reputation-total-for-today-off-by-15-points/104525#104525)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime it takes a bit for it to show the new day on the reputation page.

It looks like you lost 15 reputation today. This is almost certainly because either:

- An old, accepted answer of yours got unaccepted<strike>, which is possible if it was edited after it was accepted</strike> **Edit:** That's for voting, not accepting.
- <strike>An old, accepted answer of yours got deleted, either directly or through the question getting deleted</strike> (**Note:** ChrisF says this wouldn't show up at all, so it's probably the other.)

You gain 10 rep two days ago, adding up to a total of -5 rep for the week.

Comment: It's the latter. Rep loss from deletes doesn't show at all.

Comment: *which is possible if it was edited after it was accepted*: this is untrue. You're confusing with the ability to remove votes. An answer can **always** be unaccepted, edited or not. In this particular case, apparently someone else has posted a much clearer and better answer on the question and the OP changed the accept. This is >90% of the reasons for the unaccept.

Comment: @Chichiray Really? I was under the impression it couldn't be changed? I've seen comments like "man, now I wish I'd waited longer to accept an answer"

Comment: That's just caused by the same ignorance :) (have never seen them though)